# Error Composer Installation

Tags: php, composer-php

I have an error that showing this message when i try to install composes
please help

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far to resolve this error?

Comment: The Windows registry can be inspected (and modified) using Registry Editor. If it doesn't appear in the Start menu you can launch it by using `Run` -> `regedit.exe`. Open the path provided in the error message (`HKCU` is the short name for `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`) and remove the indicated value (values are listed on the right side of the window, in a list). Take care to not remove or modify other things then close Registry Editor and try the installation again.